# What's going wrong with C#'s string formatter?

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I'm getting the following behavior from C#s string encoder:

[Test Case Screenshot][1]

poundFromBytes should be "£", but instead it's "?".

It's as if it's trying to encode the byte array using ASCII instead of UTF-8.

Is this a bug in Windows 7 / C#'s string encoder, or am I missing something?

My real issue here is that I get the same problem when I use File.ReadAllText on an ANSI text file, and I get a related issue in a third party library.

**EDIT**

I found my problem, I was running under the assumption that UTF-8 was backwards compatible with ANSI, but it's actually only backwards compatible with ASCII. Cheers anyway, at least I'll know to make sure I have no immaterial problems with my test case next time.

Comment: `char != byte` ...Try `Console.WriteLine(sizeof(char) + " " + sizeof(byte));`

Comment: Nope, it's your code. The cast to byte is where you go wrong. Why did you think that the bug was in the .net code rather than your own code? Ask your self what ordinal value £ has and see if you think it goes into a single byte.

Comment: It's kind of annoying to need to re-type your code for my answer. Would have been nice if you included it in the question as code, rather than in image.

Comment: Especially that silly £ character :D

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, of course I assumed I was at fault. I know c# strings use more than one byte, but casting an ANSI char to a byte works fine, you get the number you'd expect, in this case 163.

Comment: You should add the code to the question and accept the best answer

Answer (score 1):

The single-byte representation of the pound sign is not valid UTF-8.

Use Encoding.GetBytes instead:

`byte[] poundBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(sPound)`

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest to the answer I needed. The information I was missing was that UTF-8 didn't fall back on ANSI, but instead ASCII which has no £ sign.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an Encoding's `GetString()` method, you should probably also use it's corresponding [`GetBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char cPound = '£';
    byte bPound = (byte)cPound; //not really valid
    string sPound = "" + cPound;

    byte[] poundBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sPound);
    string poundFromBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pountBytes);

    Console.WriteLine(poundFromBytes);
    Console.ReadKey(True);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documents here. As mentioned in the comments you can't just cast your `char` to a byte. I'll edit with a more succinct answer but I want to avoid just copy/pasting what msdn has. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx

```
char[] pound = new char[] { '£' };
byte[] poundAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pound);
```

Also, why is everyone using this GetEncoding with a hard coded argument rather than accessing UTF8 directly?

Answer (score 0):

The correct block of code should read something like:

```
        var testChar = '£';
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(new []{testChar});
        string testConvert = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

As others have said, you need to use a UTF encoder to get the bytes for a character. Incidentally characters are UTF-16 format by default (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx)